# How to use BrowserStack geolocation in Serenity BDD

Tags: browserstack, serenity-bdd

How to use BrowserStack geolocation in [Serenity BDD](https://serenity-bdd.info/) chrome property file.
It's a Java selenium web driver selenium automation.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SE. While this seems to be an interesting question, it's not as clear as necessary to give a suitable answer. Please expand on what your specific goal is and what you have tried yet.